# How to expose a prop/method of my Svelte component for testing only?

Tags: testing, svelte, sveltekit, vitest

How can I expose a prop or method of my Svelte component for testing only?

I'm aware of `accessors: true` for accessing props dynamically, but I don't want consumers of the component to be able to see the prop/method at all. It should only be exposed in my vitest run.

Example component MyComponent:

```html
<script>
    import { AnotherComplicatedApi } from 'external-package';
    const privateProp = new AnotherComplicatedApi();
</script>
```

Example vitest test:

```js
import MyComponent from '$lib/MyComponent.svelte';
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';
test( 'privateApi was initialised properly', () => {
    const { component } = render( MyComponent );
    // the following will fail, since component.privateProp does not exist.
    expect( component.privateProp.someMethod() ).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: I added an example due to the "needs details" vote, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add code conditionally using Vite's `define` constants and regular `if` statements, which should get removed by the compiler when they are pre-processed to `if (false)`. This will be somewhat restrictive in what kind of language constructs you can use, as everything will be in a block.

E.g.

```js
// vite.config.js
{
  // ...
  define: {
    TEST_BUILD: JSON.stringify(process.env.VITEST != null),
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
  const privateProp = new AnotherComplicatedApi();

  // Should be removed by optimizer in build
  if (TEST_BUILD) {
    console.log(privateProp);
  }

  // Always generates a `test` property,
  // though it will be `undefined` in regular build
  export const test = TEST_BUILD ? { privateProp } : undefined;
</script>
```

(`component.test` would be accessible without `accessors`, as the export is `const`)

To fully remove the test code, you probably would have to write or find a preprocessing plugin that transforms the source directly. E.g. to support [C-preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)-like conditional syntax:

```js
#if VITEST
export const test = { privateProp }
#endif
```

---

Another approach would be to use the dev mode utilities, though they do not appear to be documented fully, so they might change without notice.

```js
// svelte.config.js
export default {
    // ...
    compilerOptions: {
        dev: process.env.VITEST != null,
    },
}
```

```js
// in test
const { component } = render( MyComponent );
expect(component.$$.hmr_cmp.$capture_state().privateProp).toBeTruthy();
```

`$capture_state()` will include local variables, as those need to be read/updated during hot module replacement (HMR).